# Proving using the first principle of mathematical induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

This is an exercise from my Elementary number theory class, it is all about using the first principle of Mathematical Induction for proving.

The question goes,

Prove that $\sum_{j=1}^n(-1)^{j-1}j^2=1^2-2^2+3^2-\cdots+(-1)^{n-1}n^2=\frac{(-1)^{n-1}n(n+1)}{2}$  for every positive integer $n$

This is my attempt in proving this problem,

$\textbf{Step 1}$: Base case (n=1)

$\sum_{j=1}^1(-1)^{j-1}j^2= (-1)^{1-1}(1)^2= \frac{(-1)^{1-1}\cdot1(1+1)}{2} $

$$1=1$$
Therefore Base case is true.

$\textbf{Step 2}$: Induction Hypothesis

Suppose $\sum_{j=1}^n(-1)^{j-1}j^2= \frac{(-1)^{n-1}n(n+1)}{2}$ is true for $n=k$

$\implies$ $\sum_{j=1}^{k}(-1)^{j-1}j^2=(-1)^{k-1}k^2=\frac{(-1)^{k-1}n(k+1)}{2}$ is true for every positive integer $k$

$\textbf{Step 3}$: We want to show that it is also true for $n=k+1$

$\sum_{j=1}^{k+1}(-1)^{j-1}j^2= \sum_{j=1}^{k}(-1)^{j-1}j^2 +(-1)^{(k+1)-1}(k+1)^2=\frac{(-1)^{(k+1)-1}[(k+1)(k+1)+1]}{2}$

$\frac{(-1)^{k-1}k(k+1)}{2} + \frac{(-1)^{k}(k+1)^2}{1}= \frac{(-1)^{(k+1)-1}[(k+1)(k+1)+1]}{2}$

$\frac{(-1)^k(-1)^{-1}(k^2+k)+2((-1)^k(k+1)^2)}{2} = \frac{(-1)^{k}(k+1)(k+2)}{2}$

?? I don't know what to do next

Comment: You're close; to complete the inductive step you need to prove$$\frac{(-1)^{k-1}k(k+1)}{2}+(-1)^k(k+1)^2=\frac{(-1)^k(k+1)(k+2)}{2},$$which is easily done if you cancel $(-1)^k(k+1)/2$ factors.