# Solution in proving using mathematical Induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

This is a part of the proof using mathematical induction, specifically the last step where we prove the inductive step. I saw this solution on the internet, However, I cannot comprehend the solution, where did the $(-1)^k$ go in the second line of this solution proceeding to the 3rd line. How did it cancel?

$\sum_{j=1}^{k+1}(-1)^{j-1}j^2= \sum_{j=1}^{k}(-1)^{j-1}j^2 +(-1)^{(k+1)-1}(k+1)^2=\frac{(-1)^{(k+1)-1}[(k+1)(k+1)+1]}{2}$

$\frac{(-1)^{k-1}k(k+1)}{2} + \frac{(-1)^{k}(k+1)^2}{1}= \frac{(-1)^{(k+1)-1}[(k+1)(k+1)+1]}{2}$

$\frac{(-1)^k(-1)^{-1}(k^2+k)+2((-1)^k(k+1)^2)}{2} = \frac{(-1)^{k}(k+1)(k+2)}{2}$

$\frac{(-1)^k(-1)(k^2+k)+2(k^2+2k+1)}{2} = \frac{(-1)^{k}(k+1)(k+2)}{2}$

$\frac{(-1)^k(-k^2-k+2k^2+4k+2)}{2} = \frac{(-1)^{k}(k+1)(k+2)}{2}$

$\frac{(-1)^k(k^2+3k+2)}{2} = \frac{(-1)^{k}(k+1)(k+2)}{2}$

$\frac{(-1)^{k}(k+1)(k+2)}{2} = \frac{(-1)^{k}(k+1)(k+2)}{2}$

Comment: the $(-1)^k$ in this $2((-1)^k(k+1)^2)$  found on the second line

Comment: See hint [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4531963/proving-using-the-first-principle-of-mathematical-induction).